# One script tag per AngularJS Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modularity

Just started with angularjs. It's really great.
I would like to have my app to be as modular as possible.
My question: Should I have one script tag per angularjs controller (service etc)?
Is there a way to load my angular controllers (services etc) from the server, as needed? Angular does it somehow? Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

Perhaps I haven't made myself clear. I wish to have one javascript file per angularjs controller (service etc). Just like I have one file per nodejs module server-side.

Comment: What do you mean with "one script tag per angularjs controller (service etc)"? are you talking about linking the source js files?

Comment: Yes, I am. Say my app have four controllers. I would like to have each one in its own javascript file: SomeController.js, OtherController.js etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take as starting point the angular seed project.
You could find it on [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

> This project is an application skeleton for a typical AngularJS web
>   app. You can use it to quickly bootstrap your angular webapp projects
>   and dev environment for these projects.

This is the style they suggest to adopt for the controllers.js file:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

function MyCtrl1() {}
MyCtrl1.$inject = [];


function MyCtrl2() {
}
MyCtrl2.$inject = [];
```

I also suggest this approach for the development environment. You could compress, and join the files when you will deploy to production.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this actually as you are polluting the global namespace with all those controllers. Also you should group types by features: so User(UserCtrl, UserService, UserFilter, etc) instead by type: Controllers, Services

Comment: I like Brian Ford's approach (http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps.html), but when I concatenate and minify won't I be sending to the client controllers that perhaps will not be needed? I would like to download the files containing the controllers as they are needed. Or that the loaded script know will be needed.